# Webpack doesn't care about conditional style importing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass

I'm trying to build a multilingual website which has LTR and RTL languages using Vue. I've wrote an if statement to import related sass files but Webpack imports them all.

Here is the code:

```js
if (lang == 'rtl') {
  require('@/assets/bootstrap-rtl/bootstrap-rtl.css');
  require('@/assets/css/index.rtl.scss');
} else {
  require('@/assets/css/index.ltr.scss');
}
```

But when I'm trying to see the CSS ouput, both files are included!